# React Native iOS Build in Release configuration freezes on Launch Screen

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an application built using React Native 0.58.6. The iOS build works fine in Debug configuration, but not when built in Release configuration. I can reproduce this on our build server and also locally using react-native run-ios --configuration Release.

This app worked previously in Release configuration before upgrading RN version. Does anyone have any tips for how to find out more information about what may be going on or how to fix this? The app does not crash or show any errors, just stays stuck on the LaunchScreen.xib.

*Edit 1*

The build works and progresses past the loading screen in the following configurations: Android/Debug, Android/Release, iOS/Debug. It is only the iOS/Release build that is failing. Also, we've tried various xCode versions including 10.1, 10.2, and 10.2.1. Still getting the same result with each version of xCode.

Any tips on how to debug something like this? With no crash, we aren't getting crash reports, and since it's a release build there is no debugging capability or console logging.

Comment: any news on this? currently stuck on this problem using RN61.2

Comment: If I recall correctly, this actually turned out to be an issue with our pre-build script in the continuous integration system. It was not creating a required environment file during the Release build that was necessary for app startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-splash-screen you maybe forgot to hide it.

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

...

SplashScreen.hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are not using this component in our build, but this may help somebody else who is.